# Xamarin.Forms Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[SaveFileDialog in XamarinForms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5wbR.png)

My requirement is to save a file in Xamarin.Forms like below image and what ever I tried so far is:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {

        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

            string root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
            // Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/WingsPdfs");
            // myDir.Mkdir();
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path, "WingsPdfGenerated.pdf");
            FileOutputStream outs = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outs.Write(customWebView.PdfStream.ToArray());
            outs.Flush();
            outs.Close();
            try
            {
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", file));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

    }
    }
}
```

In the above code I hardcoded the location of the file but I want user to select particular location and save to the selected location.
Thank You

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkRGu.png)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. The question is a bit confusing, could you explain more?

Comment: I'm Generating a pdf in xamarin forms using Dependency service and saving the pdf file like above code but my requirement is to save the file like the image above.Thanks in advance.